# How to prevent the keyboard from popping up on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/

I am trying to use the jQuery spinner above in my website (a demo of it is available at the bottom of API).

It works really work on computers, but on mobile devices, the keyboard very annoyingly pops up every time one clicks the up/down buttons. Is it possible to prevent this from happening? The spinner does not really respond well to native functions like .on('click'), instead it has its own functions.

How do I modify the code so that the keybooard only shows up when the textbox is clicked, not the up-down buttons?

This was my attempt, it does not work:

```
$( function() {
    $('.ui-spinner a').on('click', function() {
        $(':focus').blur();
});

})  // Updated code, I can now see the focus being lost on desktops, but still not mobile devices
```

Note: I got the class name by inspecting the code generated when the spinner is created.Also, I am super new to web development so I am not sure whether I am missing an easy approach.

Comment: Have you checked out the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777669/prevent-keyboard-from-popping-on-textbox-focus-click-in-ipad-webapps

Comment: Is there error message in your console? It should be `event.preventDefault()` in your code.

Comment: an alternative way would be to add another hidden layer over the text-input

Comment: There is no error message, and the answers in the other question do not work for me. I can't use readonly attribute even though it fixes this problem because I still want the users to be able to type in numbers if they directly wish to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When step up button is clicked, the input will be focus, so mobile device display keyboard, the solution is add readonly attribute, when user click input box, remove it, on blur, add readonly attribute again.

see the code snippet to understand

```js
$( "#spinner" ).spinner();
$( "#spinner" ).click(function(event){
  $(this).removeAttr('readonly').select();
});
$( "#spinner" ).blur(function(event){
  $(this).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  
<input id="spinner" >
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, however, to type directly into the the text box, I need to click on the text box twice. The first click gets the focus, the second click brings up the keyboard. Would you happen to know  how to fix that? Thanks again, Bùi!

Comment: i have edited the code snippet, but i don't have a mobile device here to test, hope it work

Answer (score 4):

You only need to add the `readonly` attribute to the `input` tag.

```
<input id="spinner" readonly>
```

Comment: maybe look silly at first glance, but it was the easiest solution for me to popup a timepicker with no keyboard annoying!

Comment: Why does it look silly at first?

Comment: just at first glance cause it's trying to put something into a read-only element! :)

Answer (score 3):

Please make onfocus="blur()"

```
<input id="spinner" onfocus="blur()"/>
```

Comment: Not working on IOS and Android devices keyboard opens like usually.

Comment: Worked for me in Sept21 on Android, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
$( ".spinner" ).spinner();
$( ".spinner" ).click(function(event){
  $(this).removeAttr('readonly').select();

});
$( ".spinner" ).blur(function(event){
  $(this).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
  
});
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <input class="spinner" min="1" max="9" value="1" height="40px" readonly="readonly" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Comment: You forget to put jQuery min file.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add Link and Script source, Check it now but I need to highlight Spinner arrow up and down