# Why does shiny dateInput() cause the keyboard to appear in the phone?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

When I use the dateInput() in shiny use my phone, the keyboard will appear.[image]

It is work fine in My pc, but when I use the phone, keyboard will show up.
Is there any method to stop keyboard pop up of phone?
I also find the same question when I use the selectInput() function. Add the `selectize = FALSE` is useful in selectInput.
Is there any other way to stop keyboard pop up in phone? The `selectize = FALSE`  will make selection harder in  mobile devices.
`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput(
    "date",
    "What is your brithday?",
    
  ))
server <- function(input, output, session){}
  
  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46201283/9841389) answer suggests to add the [readonly](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) attribute. This can be done via `htmltools::tagAppendAttributes` or `htmltools::tagQuery`.

However, I currently can't test it:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # tagAppendAttributes(dateInput(
  #   "date",
  #   "What is your brithday?",
  # ), readonly = "", .cssSelector = "input")
  
  tagQuery(dateInput(
    "date",
    "What is your brithday?",
  ))$find("input")$addAttrs(readonly = "")$allTags()
)
server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```